# ZAP Dynamic SSL certificate option is not available

Tags: security, zap

The option to create dynamic certificates in ZAP is not available. I am running it on a local machine[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8BSM.png).

Does anyone know whether it's been removed? If not, where/how do I get to it?

I tried looking for in extensions and tried reinstalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has not been removed.
You can find it under Options / Network / Server Certificates.

Pro tip - if you put "certificate" in the Options search box then you will find all of the option screens with that word in them :)